# Class Function to a Protocol using Extension in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a protocol `SomeProtocol` which should get a class function.

```
class func doSomething() -> Bool { ... }
```

I want to use an extension:

```
extension SomeProtocol { ... }
```

to add a class function.

**Is it possible to extend a protocol with a class function?**

Answer (score 1):

You have extend the class with your protocol, so something like:

```
extension MyClass: SomeProtocol { ... }
```

Then you would implement that class func in that extension which conforms to SomeProtocol.

Answer (score 0):

**Protocols can not be extended**

You can create new protocol, that inherits from your protocol.

That is, if some type is going to conform to `ExtendedProtocol`, it has to implement `SomeProtocol` also

```
Protocol ExtendedProtocol: SomeProtocol {

class func doSomething ( ) -> Bool { ... }

}
```